# How to load scene that is made with the editor

Tags: model, load, three.js

There is a nice editor made for three.js.
You can find it here: http://threejs.org/editor/
I made a scene and exported as scene.
My question is how can I load the scene inside my webpage.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export first the object / scene then use the ObjectLoader or the SceneLoader (which will be deprecated), there are a few examples online.